# How to compile with dmd or ldc without exception and typeinfo support?

Tags: d

when I compile a relativly small codebase i see much "unnecassary" stuff for exception handling/typeinfo.
I do allready compile with -stdlib= (empty) and i do have my own replacement for the stdlib (without GC and stuff)

for example (compiled with -map):

```
0002:000025D8       __except_handler3          004045D8
0000:00000000  Abs  __except_list              00000000
...
0002:00003A04       __global_unwind            00405A04
...
```

how to get rid of this easily without ripping the .obj files appart?

Comment: I don't know the answer for ldc, but dmd doesn't really support this. (You can strip out some library support by recompiling the druntime, but the compiler still expects something to be there and tries to output the necessary tables). However, while it might not be strictly necessary (tho exceptions are pretty common in D...), this stuff doesn't hurt. You're only looking at a few kilobytes in the executable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to ommit the generation of type information in LDC with [LDC_no_typeinfo](http://wiki.dlang.org/LDC-specific_language_changes#LDC_no_typeinfo).